# Tkinter dropshadow on frame and label text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, effects, dropshadow

Is there anyway to possibly give a tkinter frame a dropshadow? it seems like it would be a basic feature but i dont see anyway how to do it?

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750939/how-to-add-shadow-to-tkinter-frame

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add shadow to tkinter frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750939/how-to-add-shadow-to-tkinter-frame)

Comment: Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try with tkinter.ttk...

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('clam')

style.configure('Custom.TFrame', background='white', borderwidth=5,
                relief='groove', padding=10, 
                foreground='black', shadow=True)

frame = ttk.Frame(root, style='Custom.TFrame')
frame.pack(padx=50, pady=50)

root.mainloop()
```