# I'm not able to add a background color or a shadow color for ttk.frame

Tags: python, tkinter, themes, openai-api, ttk

How do I add a shadow to the ttk.frame? (NOTE: I'm using the sun vally theme from github).
App: I'm creating a to-do list app. Which is just a little simple project, but I've incountered this problem and now i dont know what to do. I've tried using chatGPT but the changes it made wasn't that successful.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from functools import partial
import sv_ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x800")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title("To-do list")

# Variables
text_theme = "Change theme"
text_add = "Add"

# Theme button #
btn = ttk.Button(root, text=text_theme, command=sv_ttk.toggle_theme)
btn.place(x=10, y=760, width=120, height=30)

# header #
header = ttk.Label(root, text="To-do for today", font="Arial 20 bold")
header.place(x=195, y=5, width=210, height=100)

# Text box #
entry = ttk.Entry(root, width=45)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=140, pady=760)

# Add task button #
add = ttk.Button(root, text=text_add, command=sv_ttk.toggle_theme)
add.place(x=530, y=760, width=60, height=30)

# Shadow Style Configuration #
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("Shadow.TSeparator", background="gray")

# frame #
frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding="10")
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)

# Shadow Effect using ttk.Separator #
separator = ttk.Separator(frame, orient='vertical', style='Shadow.TSeparator')
separator.place(relx=1, rely=0, relheight=1)

# frame - button #
frm_btn = ttk.Button(frame, text="test", style="Custom.TButton")
frm_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)

# END COMMANDS #
sv_ttk.use_light_theme()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750939/how-to-add-shadow-to-tkinter-frame

Answer (score 1):

This is no solution to your problem, but it might help to understand what happens when you use your theme.

I recreated your example but used pack instead of the grid and place window manager. I believe this to be simpler to handle.

As you can see, I disabled the line to set the theme, so the background of the footer is teal. As soon as you click the switch mode button, the theme gets enabled and the styling information is lost.

I've never found an easy solution for shadows in tkinter myself, but using ttk and themes will make it even harder.

Instead of a separator I just used a frame with background color. In this case I used a tk.Frame. This is a possible way to use regular tkinter widgets that are outside the definitions of your style and theme configurations so you can still configure them yourself.

Whatever workaround you use to get your "shadow", by using tk instead of ttk you'll be able to use it including your ttk theme.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sv_ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x800")
root.resizable(False, False)

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("Footer.TFrame", background="teal")

frame_top = ttk.Frame(root)
frame_body = ttk.Frame(root)
frame_footer = ttk.Frame(root, style='Footer.TFrame')

frame_top.pack(side=tk.TOP)
frame_body.pack(side=tk.TOP)
frame_footer.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

title = ttk.Label(frame_top, text="To-do for today", font="Arial 20 bold")
title.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=30)

button_theme = ttk.Button(frame_footer, text='Switch Mode', command=sv_ttk.toggle_theme)
button_theme.pack(side=tk.LEFT, pady=10, padx=10)

separator = tk.Frame(frame_footer, bg='grey', height=30, width=2)
separator.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

entry = ttk.Entry(frame_footer, width=40)
entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=1)

button_add = ttk.Button(frame_footer, text='add')
button_add.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=10)

# sv_ttk.use_light_theme()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Nice one bro. But the thing is that if I do that the styling of the Sun Valley theme will not work on the frame. And that's not what I want. But thanks for sharing your ideas.

Comment: That exactly is the point. Whatever shadow workaround you'll try to use, it probably won't work because your theme will overwrite everything. So either forget about the theme and do it yourself or forget about the shadows. Or maybe think about other frameworks like PyQT? I gave up on having my gui looking exactly the way I want it. I try to focus on functionality.

Comment: I will try to get around it, thanks again for commenting